# R programming - How to remove special characters from a data set?

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have a data set that contains strings and special characters like the one below can be found in the data set.

[Special character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRiTy.png)

How do I remove special characters like the above from my data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions to remove unwanted characters, for example:

```
dataset$textcolumn <- gsub("[^\\w\\s]", "", dataset$textcolumn, perl=TRUE)
```

to remove everything except word characters and spaces. To do more complex replacements look into the help topic `?regexp`.

Also look into the encoding (`Encoding` and `iconv` are helpful here.), maybe the text is correct but the wrong encoding is assumed.